# Unable to capture coarse location on Google Pixel 3a

Tags: android

Tried to get coarse location lat,lon however, noticed that sometimes the lat,lon I get is 0,0.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   if (!checkPermissions()) {
     requestPermissions();
   } else {
     getLastLocation();
  }
}

 private void getLastLocation() {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        getCoarseLocation();
                    }
                });
    }

private getCoarseLocation() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

        Location l = null;

        for (int i = providers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            if (l != null) break;
        }

        double[] gps = new double[2];
        if (l != null) {
            System.out.println(l.getLatitude());
            System.out.println(l.getLongitude());
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

What could be reason for this? Any leads or links to capture coarse location using android API would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: emulator or physical device?

Comment: @DanDayne physical device

Answer (score 0):

Try scanning all providers and all locations. Don't stop on the first found.

It is possible that the gps cannot get a lock too..